# inheritance c++

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, virtual

I have two class.

```
class A:

class B: public A
{
     //new function
     void setHint(...);
}
```

And have struct data.

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<A> window_ptr;
std::stack<window_ptr> m_windowsStack;
m_windowsStack.push(std::make_shared<A>("Hint"));
m_windowsStack.push(std::make_shared<B>("Game"));
```

And have function find in stack:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> WindowManager::findWindow(std::string title)
{
    ... return result;
}
```

And use function for find element in stack:

```
auto w = findWindow("Game"); //return element type B 
w->setHint(window);
```

But it turns out that function findWindow return `type A`. I get error "'class A' has no member named 'setHint'
         w->setHint(window);"

Do I need to declare setHint function in class A as virtual function? How do I make a variable to automatically understand that it is of type B?

Comment: Just cast the result, i.e. `auto w = findWindow("Game");` -> `auto w = static_cast<B*>(findWindow("Game"));`

Comment: `class A:` is an error, please write real code. Also I am not sure if you intended `setHint` to be a variadic function

Comment: @M.M  class A: {} it's abstract class, my class big and there is a lot of unnecessary variables for this question \ functions. :)

Answer (score 5):

Without understanding your entire project, I'd say the right solution is likely to add a virtual function in the base class.

```
class A {
 public:
  virtual void setHint(/*...*/) { /* some default implementation */}
  // or pure virtual
  virtual void setHint(/*...*/) = 0;

  virtual ~A() = default; // base class should have a virtual destructor
};

class B: public A {
 public:
  void setHint(/*...*/) override;
};
```

Alternatively, If you know **for sure** that the type pointed to the return value from `findWindow` is a `B` you can simply `static_pointer_cast` it down

```
auto w = std::static_pointer_cast<B>(findWindow("Game"));
w->setHint(window);
```

If you aren't sure, and `A` is a polymorphic type (having any `virtual` functions) you can `dynamic_pointer_cast` and check for null

```
if (auto w = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(findWindow("Game"))) {
  w->setHint(window);
}
```

Comment: another option is `dynamic_cast<B&>(*w).setHint(window);` - this will throw an exception instead of undefined behaviour in case it is not the expected type

Comment: @M.M right, but not if OP is trying to not add virtual functions

Comment: He said in a comment to the question that A is an abstract class (implying it already contains virtual functions)

Comment: You might want to use [cast operators for `shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast) instead of casting the raw pointer stored.

Comment: @Holt indeed, that does eliminate the extra variable

Answer (score 2):

Your choices are:

1. Declare `setHint` virtual in class A
2. Use `dynamic_pointer_cast`

Thus

```
auto w = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(findWindow("Game"));
assert(w);  // Will be nullptr if cast fails.
w->setHint(window);
```